# How to force a deep render in React Native on a specific interval?

Tags: react-native, settimeout, use-state

How can I update a react component once every half second? I have a need to update a component to show new information as it flows in from an api. I want the component to rerender so it can display to new information at a specific interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, we could use `forceUpdate`. Unfortunately, in React Native, we don't have that luxury. Luckily, `useState` offers a deep render every time the `setState` function is called. This solution is a little hacky, but it gets the job done. Here's how it works:

```
const [inProgress, setInProgress] = useState(false); //This should be true when you want rerendering to happen.
const [updateCounter, setUpdateCounter] = useState(0); //This is the state the will force the update.

if (inProgress) {
    setTimeout(() => setUpdateCounter(updateCounter + 1), 500);
}
```

This is the simplest way I've found to do it. The interval in this example is set to 500ms. However, it could be set to whatever you want. I chose half a second because I felt it offered a responsive enough feel to the user while also giving enough time for `setState` to run.